# How to Access liferay theme images with freemarker from article template?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

How to Access liferay theme images with freemarker from article template in Liferay 6.x?

Answer (score 1):

In velocity there was a variable named `$images_folder`, so in freemarker it's probably `${images_folder}`.

Check init.vm in Liferay's parent themes, as well as the source for `VelocityVariablesImpl.java` in older versions or `TemplateContextHelper.java` in newer versions. Not sure when it was renamed and you're asking for 6.x anyway.